# Does MySQL stops searching when a match is found in a unique indexed column?

Tags: mysql, indexing, unique-index

Question is simple, but I would like to give an example:

I have a table named user in which the email field is unique indexed. The table has a total of 10 rows. Now suppose while querying the table, match for the given email ID is found in the 5th row. In this case, will MySql go ahead and look for more matches or it stops the search at 5th row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If with "unique" you really mean an **UNIQUE** defined column, than **yes**, it will stop.
But also, when databases (and each one on has its own algorithm) have an indexed column search, they don't search on table rows, they search on the index table.

Comment: Thanks. It helped :)